# How to select first block level parent with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="0">
    <h1 id="1">
        <span id="2"><span id="3">lorem ipsum</span></span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

How can I find the first parent of span#3 that is of block level (i.e. has `display: block`) using jQuery? In this case that would be `h1#1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#3").parents().filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("display") === "block";
}).first()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DFURw/

Comment: Why is strict comparison (`===`) important in this case?

Comment: @exizt To shut up code quality tools that don't realize where === is redundant ;P

Comment: It's nice and tidy code, but one caveat is that this will search every parent even when the first is a block element.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. . . I think that would be

```
$('#3').parents().each(function(){

    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
        console.log(this);
        //do your stuff if the element is block
        return false; // bail out
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is the shortest and will not search any more elements than necessary:

```
var $el = $('#3');
while ($el.css('display') !== 'block' && ($el = $el.parent().length)){}
```

When finished, $el will be either a parent element that is display: block, or if there are none it will be  a jQuery element with no items.

Answer (score 0):

[According to W3C, a block level element can have a display of anything whose contents are processed like a table or a block](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#inline-block). So, without further adieu, here is my solution. I believe you will find it to be much faster than the above solutions.

```
var elementBlockDisplays={"run-in":1,"block":1,"table-row-group":1,"table-column":1,"table-column-group":1,"table-header-group":1,"table-footer-group":1,"table-row":1,"table-cell":1,"table-caption":1,"inline-block:":1};

var getBlockParent = function(theElement){
    var cur=theElement.parentElement;
    while (cur&&!elementBlockDisplays[getComputedStyle(cur).display])
        cur=cur.parentElement;
    return cur;
};
```